# create Dynamic XML elements php

Tags: php, xml, tags, element

I need to create the Dynamic XML Elements and i have almost done it for the Value tag but I am still having some issue with Name Tag in XML.

```
<?php    
    foreach ($shot as $shotx){
        $metadata=$xml->createElement("metadata");
        $clip->appendChild($metadata);
        $name=$xml->createElement("name","shotL");
        $metadata->appendChild($name);
        $value=$xml->createElement("value",$shotx);
        $metadata->appendChild($value); 
    ?>
```

The output of the Above code is almost as i have expected instead of Name Tag. so the current output is written below:

```
<metadata> <name>shotL</name> <value>value1</value></metadata> 

<metadata> <name>shotL</name> <value>value2</value> </metadata>

<metadata> <name>shotL</name> <value>value3</value> </metadata> 

<metadata> <name>shotL</name> <value>value4</value> </metadata>

<metadata> <name>shotL</name> <value>value5</value> </metadata>
```

I would also need to have the dynamic value in the name tag like Below:

```
<metadata> <name>**shotL**</name> <value>value1</value></metadata> 

<metadata> <name>**shotL.1**</name> <value>value2</value> </metadata>

<metadata> <name>**shotL.2**</name> <value>value3</value> </metadata> 

<metadata> <name>**shotL.3<**/name> <value>value4</value> </metadata>

<metadata> <name>**shotL.4**</name> <value>value5</value> </metadata>
```

Basically the name Tag must also contain incremental Value like:

```
shotL
shotL.1
shotL.2
shotL.3
shotL.4
```

Please help me , Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Use plain `for` instead of `foreach` so that you can keep track of element index

Comment: How do I handle the end of loop condition with plain for ? The $shot variable have dynamic values a

Comment: Use `count($shot)`

Answer (score 0):

so I used this Code to solve my Problem and thanks to@har07 Idea's.

```
<?php    
$endshotc = count($shot);
for ($i=0; $i < $endshotc; $i++){
       metadata=$xml->createElement("metadata");
        $clip->appendChild($metadata);
        $name=$xml->createElement("name","shotL".$i);
        $metadata->appendChild($name);
        $value=$xml->createElement("value",$shotx[$i]);
        $metadata->appendChild($value); 
}
    ?>
```

Thank you for all help.